# Weird behavior of DataFrame operations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, orc

Consider the code:

```
val df1 = spark.table("t1").filter(col("c1")=== lit(127))
val df2 = spark.sql("select x,y,z from  ORCtable")
val df3 = df1.join(df2.toDF(df2.columns.map(_ + "_R"): _*),
  trim(upper(coalesce(col("y_R"), lit("")))) === trim(upper(coalesce(col("a"), lit("")))), "leftouter")
df3.select($"y_R",$"z_R").show(500,false)
```

This is producing the warning `WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page (2097152 bytes), try again.`The code fails `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

But if I run the following code:

```
val df1 = spark.table("t1").filter(col("c1")=== lit(127))
val df2 = spark.sql("select x,y,z from  ORCtable limit 2000000")//only difference here
//ORC table has 1651343 rows so doesn't exceed limit 2000000
val df3 = df1.join(df2.toDF(df2.columns.map(_ + "_R"): _*),
  trim(upper(coalesce(col("y_R"), lit("")))) === trim(upper(coalesce(col("a"), lit("")))), "leftouter")
df3.select($"y_R",$"z_R").show(500,false)
```

This produces the correct output. I'm at a loss why this happens and what changes. Can someone help make some sense of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: The Spark `physical execution plan` are different for the two ways of generating the same `dataframe` which can be checked by calling the `.explain()` method.

The first way uses the `broadcast-hash join` which causes `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` whereas the latter way runs the `sort-merge join` which is typically slower but does not strain the garbage collection as much.

This difference in physical execution plans is introduced by the additional `filter`operation on the `df2 dataframe`.